# Random Sound Thread--Please post a random sound

Tags: sound, recording, sharing

Please post a random sound, everybody visiting this site.

Creepy wooden door creak

Comment: Nice idea, i'll get one up soon. But, where is your sound?

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean the ACTUAL sound, I meant just the words/text but the actual sound is good too!  With the words/text, you can leave more to the imagination.

Answer (score 2):

London from inside a post box

Comment: @Mark Remember, the embed only works on Mozilla.  I recommend posting a link too.  That's a unique perspective you have there.

Comment: Thanks Auddity, I did not know that. Will add the link too from now on.

Comment: Nice capture. Care to share on how you achieved this?

Comment: Sure, so it's one of the old double width post boxes we have here in the UK like this one:

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_rOxJ-Rvzrmc/Sc42tDjBikI/AAAAAAAAARo/dor3UdxHgWI/s1600-h/Large+Post+Box.jpg

This was recorded using a zoom H4 and a pair of DPA 4061's (the high sensitivity version). They're miniature omni microphones. I put one in each side to capture the interior in stereo. Probably would not have thought about using these mics if it wasn't for hearing Chris Watson talk about them, they're so versatile - you can vary the stereo field by their spacing and are small enough to put anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my cousin's baby crying:

[soundcloud]stephensaldanha/human-baby-cry[/soundcloud]

Answer (score 1):

Instrument Panel of a Helicopter powering down

Answer (score 0):

My cat lapping water from a dish.

Answer (score 0):

Slush stomped

(Amazing gore component)